# Make the menu items of menu created, functionable using GTK+

Tags: c, menu, gtk

Here in this code I have created a menu bar and added menus and menu items to it...
But i dont know how to make the created menu items functionable... for eg: I want the 'Open' menu item of 'File' in the menu bar, open a file and display it...
I'm making a project on a Text Editor using GTK+ 3

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>


    GtkWidget     *window;
    GdkPixbuf     *icon;
    GtkWidget     *vbox;

    GtkWidget     *menubar;
    GtkWidget     *fileMenu;
    GtkWidget     *fileMi;
    GtkWidget     *editMenu;
    GtkWidget     *editMi;
    GtkWidget     *searchMenu;
    GtkWidget     *searchMi;
    GtkWidget     *newMi;
    GtkWidget     *openMi;
    GtkWidget     *saveMi;
    GtkWidget     *saveasMi;
    GtkWidget     *quitMi;
    GtkWidget     *undoMi;
    GtkWidget     *redoMi;
    GtkWidget     *cutMi;
    GtkWidget     *copyMi;
    GtkWidget     *pasteMi;
    GtkWidget     *fontMi;
    GtkWidget     *findMi;
    GtkWidget     *replaceMi;
    GtkWidget     *text_view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;

    void txt(){

    text_view = gtk_text_view_new ();
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), text_view, TRUE, TRUE, 0);


    }

    GdkPixbuf *create_pixbuf (const gchar *filename)
    {
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GError    *error = NULL;

    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file (filename, &error);

    if (!pixbuf)
    {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", error->message);
    g_error_free (error);
    }

    return pixbuf;
    }

    static void fileOpen(GtkWidget *load, gpointer window)
    {
    GtkWidget *choose;
    GtkFileChooserAction action= GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;

    choose     =    gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Choose a file to open",  GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_STOCK_OK, GTK_RESPONSE_OK, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, NULL);
    if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(choose)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
    {

    char *path     = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(choose));
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, path, -1);
    }

    gtk_widget_destroy(choose);
    }

    static void fileSave(GtkWidget *save, gpointer window)
    {
    GtkWidget *saved;

    saved     =    gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Choose a file to open",  GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE, GTK_STOCK_OK, GTK_RESPONSE_OK, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(saved);

    gint resp    =     gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(saved));

    gtk_widget_destroy(saved);
    }


    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {


    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    icon = create_pixbuf ("Web.png");

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Write Pad");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 500, 400);
    gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_icon (GTK_WINDOW (window), icon);

    vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);

    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new ();
    fileMenu = gtk_menu_new ();


    fileMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("File");
    newMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("New");
    openMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Open");
    saveMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Save");
    saveasMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Save As");
    quitMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Quit");

    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new ();
    editMenu = gtk_menu_new ();

    editMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Edit");
    undoMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Undo");
    redoMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Redo");
    cutMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Cut");
    copyMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Copy");
    pasteMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Paste");
    fontMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Font");

    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new ();
    searchMenu = gtk_menu_new ();

    searchMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Search");
    findMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Find");
    replaceMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Replace");

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu (GTK_MENU_ITEM (fileMi), fileMenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), newMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), openMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), saveMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), saveasMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (fileMenu), quitMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (menubar), fileMi);

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu (GTK_MENU_ITEM (editMi), editMenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(editMenu), undoMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(editMenu), redoMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(editMenu), cutMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(editMenu), copyMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (editMenu), pasteMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (editMenu), fontMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (menubar), editMi);

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu (GTK_MENU_ITEM (searchMi), searchMenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(searchMenu), findMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(searchMenu), replaceMi);

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    txt();
    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (text_view));

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (quitMi), "activate", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (newMi), "activate", G_CALLBACK (main), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (openMi), "activate", G_CALLBACK(fileOpen), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (saveMi), "activate", G_CALLBACK(fileSave), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: For starters: you're not passing the window to the activate callback: `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (openMi), "activate", G_CALLBACK(fileOpen), NULL);` should be `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (openMi), "activate", G_CALLBACK(fileOpen), (gpointer) window);`<-- the `gpointer` (a `void *`) is how you can pass additional data to the callback

Comment: Can you please edit the codes and post it here?...    I'm new to it so its tough for me

Comment: You're already connecting to the `activate` signal, so where's the problem?

Comment: @oldtechaa: Problem is a name conflict: global variable called `window` + function argument `gpointer window` <-- window isn't always what it seems. @OP: Posted an answer that should help you on your way, if something is unclear, check [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/index.html)

Comment: @Elias, thanks for explaining the bearings that has. I'm not real familiar with C, but now that you point it out, I can certainly see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the problem you have is caused by the fact that all of your widgets are global variables, but your `fileOpen` function takes a `gpointer window` argument:

```
//global
GtkWidget *window;

//gpointer window argument -> local variable, not global
static void fileOpen(GtkWidget *load, gpointer window)
{
    GtkWidget *choose;
    GtkFileChooserAction action= GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;

    choose = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new(
        "Choose a file to open",
        GTK_WINDOW(window),//window is not global, but function argument here !
        GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_STOCK_OK, GTK_RESPONSE_OK, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, NULL
    );
    if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(choose)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
    {
        char *path = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(
            GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(choose)
        );
        gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, path, -1);
    }
    gtk_widget_destroy(choose);
}
```

A quick fix would be to rename the argument to something like `gp_data` or something. A better fix would be to *not* use a global variable, and instead rely on the `gpointer` to pass on the objects you need:

```
g_signal_connect(
    G_OBJECT (openMi),
    "activate",
    G_CALLBACK(fileOpen),
    (gpointer)text_view // text_view and buffer needn't be global now
);
```

And then use the gpointer argument to get the window and anything else you might need. You could also use a custom `struct` or array of widgets to pass to the callback in case you need more stuff to work with, but in this case, you should be OK with just passing the text_view widget, and changing the callback to something like this:

```
static void fileOpen(GtkWidget *load, gpointer widget)
{
    //get the buffer
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(
        GTK_TEXT_VIEW (widget)
    );
    //get window from text_View widget passed to callback
    //so window doesn't have to be global either...
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel(
        widget
    ), *choose;
    GtkFileChooserAction action= GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;

    choose = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new(
        "Choose a file to open",
        GTK_WINDOW(window),
        GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_STOCK_OK, GTK_RESPONSE_OK, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, NULL
    );
    if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(choose)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
    {
        char *path = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(
            GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(choose)
        );
        gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, path, -1);
    }
    gtk_widget_destroy(choose);
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code, but this should be enough to get you started. You'll have to change the code you have a bit, but you should be able to get rid of all of those global variables simply by passing the right widget to the callbacks.

As always: [Read the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/index.html), just adding the link to the answer for future reference